# dead keys not working in java app

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, java, x11, dead-keys

The Arduino IDE is based on a java application called processing. While typing text into processing, it refuses to accept any of the characters under dead keys like " ' ^. As a work around I:

- Open another window (usually my browser or mail client);
- I type the character I need;
- Select and copy the character onto my clip board;
- Copy the character into processing.

What do I have to do to make processing accept characters under dead keys? Disabling dead keys is not an option.

Comment: I tagged this question as 'shortcut-keys', but I feel it should be tagged as 'dead-keys'. I haven't got enough rep to add a new tag. Can someone consider the 'dead-keys' tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out a work around. In KDE the keyboard configuration can be set in:

- System Settings
- Keyboard Settings
- Layout
- Select 'Show indicator'
- Select 'Per window'
- Add
- Select a variant without 'dead keys', eg. "English (US, with Euro on 5)"

After applying these settings, I select the window for input focus and I click the indicator in the system tray when I want to switch the keyboard configuration.
The keyboard setting needs only be set once per window and is rememberd over program restarts.